# Why don't classes apply to Angular directives?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, class, angularjs-directive

I'm a little confused how Angular directives are supposed to render as DOM elements.

My directive template elements take classes fine, and they render at the correct dimensions, regardless of the directive element's dimensions.

The issue is the rendered directive element itself does take on class properties, which to me makes it look odd in the DOM, as it has an `auto` height.

Here's a visual of my issue:

[image: photo1]

Depicted is my directive element, seen here:

[image: photo2]

You can see that the `months` class has been applied to the directive, but its properties have not propagated. So the height and width of the directive go to `auto`, even though I want `60px`. What is the issue?

Directive:

```
<month ng-model="month" class="months"></month>
```

Partial template:

```
app.directive('month', function() {
  return {
    scope:{},
    template:'<div class="months">test</div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.addClass('months');
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Did you try `ng-class="months"`?

Comment: It has the same effect. On mouseover of the DOM in Chrome Inspector, the directive displays the right height and width. But it isn't actually appearing that way.

Comment: It's a block element, right?

Comment: Make a fiddle, but this is probably due to missing `display: block;` on the `<month>` element.

Comment: Also, you may want to set replace: true in your directive, since you're invoking a directive as an HTML element. This will remove the contrived element and replace it with the div you're expecting...

Comment: I was thinking that. I will add fddle shortly.

Answer (score 0):

As @mosho mentioned in comments, it is probably due to a missing `display: block` on the `<month>` element.

To expand on this, [the initial value for the `display` style is `inline`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display), which would apply unless overriden in a stylesheet somewhere, such as the default browser stylesheet, or the stylesheet(s) you've including on the page. As `<month>` is a custom html element, it won't be mentioned in the default browser stylesheet, and as such will be treated to have `display: inline`, so height and width styles are ignored.